# Starvation with food

Tags: nutrition, starvation

How long might someone live If they give up on eating? Eating only 100-200 calories a day and a few small glasses of fluids

Answer (score 4):

The currently recognized world record in fasting - by drinking only water and taking multivitamin supplements - is *382 days* by a 27 years old man who went from 207 to 82 kg in this time ([Postgradual Medical Journal, 1973](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2495396/pdf/postmedj00315-0056.pdf), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angus_Barbieri%27s_fast)). This was a medically supervised experiment and should be considered a gross exception.

For a healthy adult with normal initial weight eating nothing or 100-200 calories worth of food per day, the realistic period to survive and remain healthy would be about *a month* ([Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-long-can-a-person-survive-without-food/), [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-17095605)).

I can't answer this for a cancer patient (one of the tags in the question is "cancer"). It is known that some people have attempted to cure cancer by fasting; this is a matter of a personal belief; scientifically it is not recognized as successful treatment. Fasting may reduce the side effects of chemotherapy, though ([Aging, 2009](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2815756/)).